# REST API: best practice for sharing resources across versions

Tags: rest, flask, model

I am building a project with a current directory as follows:

```
app
-- api
---- v1
---- v2
-- admin
-- models
```

(The project is built with Flask, and so 'admin', 'v1' and 'v2' have their own blueprints).

I am new to REST APIs and am wondering what is the best practice for sharing resources. The admin panel needs to have access to the models, but should both the API versions also have access, or retain their own models in the case of breaking changes? I am trying to ensure longevity but do not want to repeat code. The same goes for common, helper functions and errors; should they be shared or reside in their own version directory?